# MongoDB generate tree structure with child reference data

Tags: json, mongodb, tree

I want to get the tree structure from  child reference data like this:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("599f6e99a428843c34977669"),
"PI" : "A1",
"CI" : [
    "B1",
    "B2"
]},{
"_id" : ObjectId("599f6e99a428843c3497766a"),
"PI" : "B2",
"CI" : [
    "C1",
    "C2"
]},{
"_id" : ObjectId("599f6e99a428843c3497766b"),
"PI" : "A2",
"CI" : [
    "B3",
    "B4"
]},{
"_id" : ObjectId("599f6e99a428843c3497766c"),
"PI" : "B4",
"CI" : [
    "C1",
    "C3"
]},{
"_id" : ObjectId("599f7216a428843c3497766d"),
"PI" : "C1",
"CI" : [
    "D1",
    "D2"
]}
```

I refer the guide https://www.codementor.io/slavko/storing-tree-structures-in-mongodb-example-code-du107tk8d 
But still not resolve my question.

How can I get the tree structure just like:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("599f6e99a428843c34977669"),
"PI" : "A1",
"CI" : [
        "B1",
        {
        "PI" : "B2",
        "CI" : [
                {
                "PI" : "C1",
                "CI" : [
                        "D1",
                        "D2"
                        ]
                },
                "C2"
                ]
        }
        ]},{
"_id" : ObjectId("599f6e99a428843c3497766b"),
"PI" : "A2",
"CI" : [
        "B3",
        {
        "PI" : "B4",
        "CI" : [
                {
                "PI" : "C1",
                "CI" : [
                        "D1",
                        "D2"
                        ]
                },
                "C3"
                ]
        }
        ]}
```

In addition, I hope that I can get TOP ancestors by specific CI.

For example:

D1 -> A2,A1

C3 -> A2

Comment: There is nothing that is going to return a recursive structure of a "tree" in a query operation, nor should there be. This is not the job of a database. If you want a "visual tree" then it is up to you to retrieve the required nodes and build the visual representation. When we talk about modelling trees in databases, it's usually about storing parent or ancestor node references in a way that can be easily "queried". Since storing a hierarchical nesting does not make for easy "queries" we store differently. But visual construction is an entirely different thing to storage.

Comment: It's a complex aggregation, but you can https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/